# How to fix output in count query mysql (flask)

Tags: python, mysql, flask

How can I fix the output in my count query mysql (flask)

```
def addcart():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    if 'uid' not in session:
        noOfItems = 0
    else:
        uid = session['uid']
        cur.execute("SELECT count(id_phone) FROM cart WHERE id_users = " + str(uid))
        noOfItems = cur.fetchall()
    return (noOfItems)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    noOfItems = addcart()
    return render_template("index.html", noOfItems=noOfItems)
```

in my navbar

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-more i-left">
<small><span class="badge badge-primary">{{noOfItems}}</span></small>
</a>
```

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coDlz.png) : `({'count(id_phone)': 3},)`

Comment: What's your question? And please post your data in a reproducible format.

Comment: @Ekko PRas.  Never write your queries like this. Your query is vulnerable to SQL injections. Use always parameterized querying.

Comment: @BenG how to fix this problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/coDlz.png  -> ({'count(id_phone)': 3},)

Comment: @AKHILMATHEW thanks bro for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_num_of_items():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    if 'uid' not in session:
        num_of_items= 0
    else:
       uid = session['uid']
       cur.execute("SELECT count(id_phone) FROM cart WHERE id_users = " + str(uid))
       # cur.fetchone() return a dict with a single key:value pair
       num_of_items =  [v for v in cur.fetchone().values()][0]
    return num_of_items
```

Comment: this method doesn't work, i use flask with mysql  -> OUTPUT : {'count(id_phone)': 3}

Comment: addcart() should return a number (int). Can you print the returned value of the function before you 'return'?

Comment: I have modified the code and added the 'print'. Can you see the output when you run it?

Comment: Output : 
Number of items is: {'count(id_phone)': 3}

Comment: still like this

Comment: Another print was added in order to understand what you get from the DB call.

Comment: If the type is 'dict' I think the tmp.keys()[0] will do the job.

Comment: TypeError: values() takes no arguments (1 given) | :(

Comment: TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing,  it try values(0) not working

Comment: Give it another try now. :-)

Comment: Great. Use always parameterized querying. See https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing your SQL SELECT statement to the following and see if that resolves your issue:

```
cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cart WHERE id_users = " + str(uid) +";")
```

then change the following to:

```
noOfItems = cur.fetchone()
return noOfItems[0]
```

`noOfItems` will hold a tuple with one element, the value of `COUNT(*)` i.e. the number of items in your cart where the id of the user is `uid`.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: OUTPUT : KeyError: 0 , if i change return noOfItems OUTPUT : {'count(*)': 3}

Comment: did you change your sql stmt as I suggested? Did you also change the cursor method to fetchone?

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: change noOfItems[0] to noOfItems, changed my answer to this

Comment: try my latest suggestion, see comment above and edited answer

Comment: Not working bro i try your suggestion and  OUTPUT : {'count(*)': 3}

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable , this error indicates you have an integer so you just have to return it. What does your code look like exactly?